# Start Dynamics CRM for Phone with parameters

Tags: android, dynamics-crm

Is it possible to start the Dynamics CRM app programmatically from another app and pass for exemple an ID of a contact to open it directly ?

Or is it possible to know what are the available parameters to pass to an Android app ?

For exemple :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
```

I tried :

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.microsoft.crm.crmphone");
launchIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://org.crm4.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=cont‌​act&pagetype=entityrecord&id=%7B0e0cf917-005c-e511-80f8-3863bb357fc0%7D")); 
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

It opens the app but on the homepage and not on the right contact

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the upcoming version, you will be able to use deep links.

[App-to-app deep linking: Enables other mobile apps (such as email or your custom web-based app) to link and directly navigate to a record, view, or dashboard in CRM mobile apps.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/get-ready-for-the-next-release.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CRM has URL addressable forms. So you can open records by URL if you know the record `guid`.

[Open forms, views, dialogs and reports with a URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328483.aspx)

E.g. this will open a contact with the given id.

```
http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=contact&pagetype=entityrecord&id=%7B91330924-802A-4B0D-A900-34FD9D790829%7D
```